# How do you rotate axis text on Seaborn JointGrid?

Tags: seaborn

[image]

How do you rotate the text along the x-axis to avoid unreadable text like the one above?

```py
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))   
    g = sns.JointGrid(x='u',y='t',data = tdata)
    g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.histplot)
    plt.show()
```

And `plt.figure` also can't work on `JoinGrid`,

Answer (score 0):

You can get axes with [`g.ax_joint`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20then%20plot%20by%20accessing%20the%20ax_joint%2C%20ax_marg_x%2C%20and%20ax_marg_y%20attributes%2C%20which%20are%20matplotlib.axes.Axes%20objects%3A) and from here your can set you axis attributes.

### Solution 1: [`tick_params()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
g = sns.JointGrid(x="u", y="t", data=tdata)
g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.histplot)
g.ax_joint.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

### Solution 2: [`set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html)

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
g = sns.JointGrid(x="u", y="t", data=tdata)
g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.histplot)
g.ax_joint.set_xticklabels(g.ax_joint.get_xticks(), rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

### Solution 3: [`get_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html)

With this you can iterate over all the ticks and change their rotation individually.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
g = sns.JointGrid(x="u", y="t", data=tdata)
g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.histplot)
for tick in g.ax_joint.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(30)
plt.show()
```

#### PS:

xticklabels can be different for precision based on the precision value return by each function.